# Time addition not working in PHP

Tags: php, time, addition

I have assigned the variable as

```
$tot_time=strtotime("h:i:s",  time());
```

then i add the time using a loop with:

```
$tot_time=  strtotime($tot_time)+strtotime($result_row->time);
```

then, i print the total time after the loop using:

```
echo date("h:i:s",$tot_time);
```

i get the last values from the loop.

Comment: What are you expecting? What is does `$result_row->time` return? What are you getting?

Comment: $result_row->time gives the times as like 07:00:00, 08:00:00 and 08:00:00 When first iteration complete in loop, i need time as 07:00:00   and 2nd iteration ending 15:00:00 and 3rd iteration ending 23:00:00 But its not giving actual results. its returns as like 1st iteration:07:00:00, 2nd iteration:07:31:44 3rd iteration: 02:31:44> The code is: $tot_time=strtotime("h:i:s",  time()); $tot_time += strtotime($result_row->time);
echo date("h:i:s",$tot_time);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're badly abusing strtotime(). WHy not just leave the time values as integers as they already are?

```
$tot_time += strtotime($result_row->time);
```

$tot_time is **ALREADY** an integer, so there is literally no point in running it through strtotime(). And you can't really use this method for adding together time intervals. PHP's date system works on timestamps, which are seconds-since-1970.

If your $tot_time naturally exceeds 24 hours, you're going to get a "tomorrow" time, e.g. You yon't get "25 hours", you'll get "1 day and 1 hour". You'll only print out "1hour", and now your time interval is very very wrong.